# Seaborn values are missed in the plot

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

Hello I try to create a plot with seaborn  with the Following code , but i got 0.00% values in the plot.

height and total are correct but there are only 0.00 values.
Any idea please?
thanks[image]

```
tmp = pd.crosstab(df_trans['card6'], df_trans['isFraud'], normalize='index') * 100
    tmp = tmp.reset_index()
    tmp.rename(columns={0:'NoFraud', 1:'Fraud'}, inplace=True)

plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
plt.suptitle('Card 6 Distributions', fontsize=22)

plt.subplot(221)
g = sns.countplot(x='card6', data=df_trans)
# plt.legend(title='Fraud', loc='upper center', labels=['No', 'Yes'])
g.set_title("Card6 Distribution", fontsize=19)
g.set_ylim(0,500000)
g.set_xlabel("Card6 Category Names", fontsize=17)
g.set_ylabel("Count", fontsize=17)
for p in g.patches:
    height = p.get_height()

    g.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2.,
            height + 3,
            '{:1.2f}%'.format(height/total*100),
            ha="center",fontsize=14) 


plt.subplot(222)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in python 2,

```
height/total * 100
```

returns an integer.
I suggest:

```
height/total * 100.0
```

**EDIT:**
I suggest:

```
float(height)/total * 100
```

So that python knows you want a float.  My previous answer converted the number to a float, but only once it was too late.  Integer division, which is the default in python 2, is equivalent to `int(height/total)` in python 3.  to change this behavior, you can also add:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Comment: Thanks, but still the same problem

Comment: Can you provide a more useable code sample?  Maybe something with a smaller data frame constructed in the code?

Comment: I think I was able to reproduce your issue, see my edits above